# Type error when adding providesTags in RTK Query

Tags: reactjs, typescript, rtk-query

I'm trying to set up cache invalidation for my project with RTK Query, but I get a type error when following the official documentation. The goal is to invalidate individual items in the fetched list of resources, but I get stuck just trying to provide one general tag:

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react';

export const remoteScriptsApi = createApi({
    baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
        baseUrl: '/api', prepareHeaders: (headers) => {
            headers.set('Accept', 'plain/text, application/json');
            return headers;
        }
    }),
    endpoints: (builder) => ({
        getScenes: builder.query<number[], void>({
            query: () => ({ url: '/scenes' }),
            providesTags: ['Scenes']
        }),
    })
})
```

The ['Scenes'] get underlined displaying the following error message:

```
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'FullTagDescription<never>'.ts(2322)
```

I'm quite new to TypeScript, but I've still tried to dig in the type files for RTK Query to find out where and why "never" is expected. No luck though.

Let me know if more background on my project and/or code is needed! Thanks!

Comment: Please provide reproducible example

Comment: @captain-yossarian I pasted the whole file now, do you require other files as well?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I'm not familiar enough with API in RTK, but I played a bit with typescript there and found out that if you declare `tagTypes` in your createApi object it solves problem:

```
export const remoteScriptsApi = createApi({
    baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
        baseUrl: '/api', prepareHeaders: (headers) => {
            headers.set('Accept', 'plain/text, application/json');
            return headers;
        }
    }),
    tagTypes: ['Scenes'], // <---- declare your tagTypes before you use them
    endpoints: (builder) => ({
        getScenes: builder.query<number[], void>({
            query: () => ({ url: '/scenes' }),
            providesTags: ['Scenes']
        }), ...
```

Comment: Haha, maybe I should actually follow the documentation if I state that I'm following the documentation... Thanks Oro, of course I just forgot to declare my TagTypes! Well, hopefully my simple mistake resulting in a SO question will save someone else some time in the future!

Comment: Wow, that's interesting, I would expect typescript to only function like this if working with Enums, can it determine the "values" of arbitrary strings like this or am I misunderstanding what's happening here?

Comment: And for anyone interested in the docs:
https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/createApi#tagtypes